# How to get it where the url always has a slash at the end html

Tags: html, css, express

I'm working on my website and I have a problem where if the domain doesn't have a / at the end (so like https://domain.name/example) it doesn't show the css/javascript. Is there a way to make sure it has it at the end? I've tried looking it up but I don't know what I could do. If you could provide any info that would be great!

Comment: And what path to the css/javascript do you use? do you prepend it with `./`? i.e `./mycss.css`

Comment: No, I do `dashboard/js/script.js` That Most likely is the cause, Should I do `./`?

Comment: Yes, `./` will give a relative path, and `/` is absolute. This means that if the URL is `example.com/page1`. `./script.js` will be the file located at `/page1/script.js`. While `/script.js` will be the file at `/script.js`. So I would guess that you want to simply prepend a `/`.

Comment: Ah I see, If you want answer the question and I will mark it as right :D

Comment: Without `./` the browser is looking for `https://domain.name/dashboard/js/script.js`, because `/example` is treated as a file and not a directory